Convert a string num to an int and write to an SQL file?
I have a price column in my .sql file that is currently a string of numbers (prices). I want to use python to modify the string of numbers and convert them into actual numbers (floats to be specific). This is so I don't have to keep using the ::numeric type cast to do some arithmetic functions such as SUM or AVG.
-- SQL input (1000 lines):
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (1, 'Suzuki', 'Vitara', '$44490.95');
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (2, 'Ford', 'Explorer Sport Trac', '$292375.11');

-- Python Script

-- SQL output (1000 lines):
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (1, 'Suzuki', 'Vitara', 44490.95);
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (2, 'Ford', 'Explorer Sport Trac', 292375.11);

I managed to remove the '$' sign with this in Python:
#Python Script
import re

def convert_to_num():
    term = re.compile('(\\$)([\\d.]+)')

    file_in = 'car.sql'
    file_out = 'car1.sql'
    with open(file_in, 'r') as f_in:
        with open(file_out, 'w') as f_out:
            for line in f_in.readlines():
                res = term.search(line)
                if res is not None:
                    print(res.group(2))
                    fix = re.sub('(\\$)([\\d.]+)', res.group(2), line)
                    f_out.writelines(fix)
                else:
                    f_out.writelines(line)

But I don't know how to move forward from here. Also, is it possible to modify the file in place or do I really have to save the modification into another file?
I can just regenerate the TABLE from Mockaroo and use 'numbers (w/ decimals)' for the prices instead of 'money' but I got curious if I could do it and now I'm in this hole.
Wanted to convert string num to int/float num and save to an .sql file

It isn't necessary to parse the file line by line. A file with 10k insert lines is only about a 1Mib, so you can just read the whole file into memory. If you want to modify the input file, use separate (i.e. non-nested) with-blocks: (1) with open(file_in) as f: s = re.sub(r"'\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'", r"\1", f.read()); (2) with open(file_in, 'w') as f: f.write(s).


You imply that  the price field a money type, is that the case? 2) If so and you want to change that in the table in place you could do something like alter table car alter column price type numeric.


As example per my comment:
create table money_test(id integer, price money);

insert into money_test values (1, '$10.00'), (2, '50.00'), (3, '$25.00');

select * from money_test ;
 id | price  
----+--------
  1 | $10.00
  2 | $50.00
  3 | $25.00

alter table money_test alter column price type numeric;

select * from money_test ;
 id | price 
----+-------
  1 | 10.00
  2 | 50.00
  3 | 25.00


ohhh I understand now. Yeah that works. Thanks!

You can accomplish this directly with SQL. First use the replace() function to remove the $, then use cast() function to the desired numeric type. So somethin like:
insert into car (id, make, model, price) 
      values (1, 'Suzuki', 'Vitara', cast(replace('$44490.95','$','') as numeric))
           , (2, 'Ford', 'Explorer Sport Trac', cast(replace('$292375.11','$','')as numeric)); 

You could also use the Postgres specific :: to cast to desired type:
insert into car (id, make, model, price) 
         values (1, 'Toyota', 'Prius', replace('$32678.49','$','')::numeric);


Wouldn't this mean that I'd have to do this one by one? How would I do it en masse because I have to apply it to 1000 lines
